# Javascript: append to array with result of async queries

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I have an async function which I want to contain the result of three async queries (they are firebase firestore queries).  I loop, and attempt to append the result of the queries to an array in a wider scope.  Unfortunately, the result of the `brands` array is always empty.  Is this because I need to `await` the inner query? Is there a better way to handle this entirely?

```
async function getBrandsHelper() {
  var brands = [];
  await db
    .collection("global")
    .doc("display-data")
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      const displayData = doc.data();
      const keys = ["p1", "p2", "p3"];
      for (const i in keys) {
        const k = keys[i];
        const product = displayData[k];
        db.collection("products")
          .doc(product)
          .get()
          .then(doc => {
            var brandData = { id: product };
            const productData = doc.data();
            brandData["image"] = productData["image"];
            brandData["title"] = productData["title"];
            brandData["description"] = productData["description"];
            brandData["url"] = productData["url"];
            brands.push(brandData);
            return;
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
          });
      }
      return;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
    });
  return brands;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor your code to use either `async/await` or `then/catch` callbacks. This is not mandatory but will make you code more understandable. Think of them as alternatives to achieve the same result: to make asynchronous code more managebale.

This is how you would do it with `async/await` (observe how there is not `then/catch` involved):

```
async function getBrandsHelper() {
  let brands = [];
  try {
    // You await for the doc1 to be ready
    const doc1 = await db
      .collection("global")
      .doc("display-data")
      .get();

    const displayData = doc1.data();
    const keys = ["p1", "p2", "p3"];
    for (const i in keys) {
      const k = keys[i];
      const product = displayData[k];

      // You await for each tmpDoc before moving on
      const tmpDoc = await db.collection("products")
        .doc(product)
        .get();

      let brandData = {
        id: product
      };
      const productData = tmpDoc.data();
      brandData["image"] = productData["image"];
      brandData["title"] = productData["title"];
      brandData["description"] = productData["description"];
      brandData["url"] = productData["url"];
      brands.push(brandData);
    }

    return brands;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return []
  }
}
```

To do it with `then/catch` callbacks would be a little bit more complicated (due to the async calls inside the for loop). You would have to store all the Promises in an array and then use something like `Promise.all` to retrieve all the docs to work with.

Anyway, it seems that you are lacking a more deep understanding of Promises and async code in Javascript. I suggest you to read on a little be more about Promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) and about the use of `async/await` and how it relates to promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Answer (score -2):

You should use promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise
Build your promises and use `Promise.all` to do something after all of them have been executed.

Comment: async  returns a promise. .then() can only run on a returned promise. Await also returns a promise. theres promises all over this, do your research

Comment: I don't know why you say that and why I've been voted down but I faced the same problem and I used promises to get the expected result.

Comment: It is already using Promises. The problem is that he is not using them correctly.